# Edit queue on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

The suggested edits queue is usually not full on Stack Overflow. However, sometimes (especially during the evenings), it is impossible to edit anything because the edit queue is full. This seems to be consistent. Is this a tech issue or is there something really wrong?

Comment: This might have something to do with the diurnal peaks of activity of the site

Comment: Yes, but I can't edit anything, this might be a bug but might not.

Comment: Do you get a message that the edit queue is currently full? Then it probably is - suggested edits is a busy one. Currently it sits at 450 out of 500, though, so you should be able to suggest edits.

Comment: @OlegValter I do get the message that message sometimes in the evenings, however I can edit posts currently. I think this might have to do with a cached endpoint (if that is even possible).

Comment: @arihanta - most likely the queue really is at 500 when you edit it then. I am fairly active in reviewing suggested edits and see that it sits at ~450 every day, so at some point during the day when people aren't that active it is bound to overflow

Comment: Then it seems that it is a actual problem (maybe increase the edit limit?).

Comment: @arihanta - no, I don't think the limit is the problem. We have too many too minor edits and not enough reviewers (the latter in no small part due to the experience is not rewarding in the slightest - you feel like a human neural network when doing this and feeling of "contributing" can only get one so far before burning out).

Comment: If existing reviews were used for ML training to eventually replace reviewers then sure, but I am unaware of any intention to do so. In the absence of that, the reviews are just thankless busywork.

Comment: if you are wondering how you could help, here is a couple of notes after looking through your 3 suggestions: 1. Don't waste your and reviewers' time on bad posts (Java answer). 2. Remove noise like "I just cant figure out the fault that I am making, maybe you can help me out" (unity question). 3. In general, leave the tag edits to users with full edit privilege - we can do that unilaterally (and at 10K - inline).

Comment: @arihanta increasing the size treats just part of the symptom. What you actually get is longer a longer queue, which means more time to go through it because you have the same amount of reviewers at the end of the day. And reviews are rate-limited, so it's not like a single person can go and complete 400 reviews a day and just clear the queue. You can only action 20 reviews a day, under some circumstances 40. Bumping the limit of the review cap is also not an option because not all reviewers go to the max every day. It'd also be a bit presumptuous to expect them to.

Comment: *the edit queues are full* - you write in plural form here, but I know only of 1 edit queue on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @jps - just a typo methinks (although some believe tag wiki suggested edits and normal edits to be separate [which they aren't])

Comment: @OlegValter when you have to wait 30 days for an approval of a wiki edit, you might think it's a different queue, but it's really not. I edited the question now.

Comment: @jps - my personal record is 1.5 months [although I am unsure whether to laugh or cry] :) And the streak ended simply because SE rolled out the "welcome to the queue popup" which did something to wiki suggestions as they were all shuffled to the front of the queue...

Comment: This seems to be a localized issue then. Perhaps most of the editors are located in the US. As a result I (currently on UTC+2) can’t edit at all during my working hours, because that’s mostly “during the night” in the US.

Comment: Something needs to be done here… I experience edit queue being full quite often. Probably reputation to get the edit privilege should be set higher.